# Xcode Mac youtube search box

Tags: xcode, macos, xcode4, youtube

I'm currently developing an app that uses a search box for youtube videos.

Can someone suggest how to do the search itself? (I mean how to get the search results into a text line)?

Answer (score 0):

You will probably want to use the [Youtube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/reference#Response_Codes). The documentation has a great section on "Searching For Videos":

> To search for videos, send a GET request to the following URL,
> appending the appropriate query parameters to your request:
>
> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos
>
> For example, a request to the following URL searches for the second
> set of 10 recently uploaded videos matching the query term "football"
> but not matching the query term "soccer":
>
> https://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos?q=football+-soccer&orderby=published&start-index=11&max-results=10&v=2